# How to enhance performance of sql query?

Tags: oracle, performance, perl, shell, sqlplus

Below is the major part of my script which interacts with an Oracle database through SQL*Plus.

```
  #--------------- Now connecting to sqlplus

         `$SQLPLUS \@${basePath}/VoucherQuery.sql $startdate> ${basePath}/logs/QueryResult.$currentDate.log`;
         if ( $? == 0) {
             logger("Processing with the sqlplus is completed. For more details check ${basePath}/logs/QueryResult.$currentDate.log ", 0); }
         else {
             logger("Not able to fetch data from sqlplus. Please check", 1); exit;} 



         #print "select * from sample where SERIALNUMBER = $serial\n"; 

         open (FH, "${basePath}/logs/QueryResult.$currentDate.log") or die "Can't open query ${basePath}/logs/QueryResult.$currentDate.log file: $!\n"; 

         my ($serial_number, $state, $at, $operator_id, $old_state);
         while (my $data = <FH>) {
               chomp ($data);
               #print $data."\n";          
               my @data = split (/\s+/, $data); 
               my ($serial_number, $state, $at, $operator_id, $old_state) = @data[0..4];


               my ($date, $time) = split (/T/, $at);
               $date =~ s/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$3-$month{$2}-$1/; 
               $date =~ s/(.*)(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1$3/; 


              print WFH "$circle,$date,$time,$operator_id,$serial_number,$old_state,$state\n";
               }
           close(FH);
    close(WFH);

-------------------------------------------------------------
>cat VoucherQuery.sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT serialnumber, state, at, operatorid, lag(state) OVER ( PARTITION BY serialnumber ORDER BY at) AS previous FROM VOUCHER) WHERE at LIKE '&1';
```

But the database table contains millions of records and even a simple `select count(*)` query isn't able to generate output. Now the problem is that no constraints have been defined while creating the database.

I have experience of scripting, but I am quite a novice in SQL queries as far as performance is concerned.

I want to ask

- How much difference will it make if I define the primary key constraint within the table? (It is a third-party server so I have to be sure before making any changes.)
- Will an index improve the performance? How could they help in this specific query?
- Should I break this query into more, simpler queries?

Here is the table description

```
SQL> DESC VOUCHER;
Name                        Null?                 Type
--------------------------  -------- -------------------------------
SERIALNUMBER                          VARCHAR2(20)
STATE                                 VARCHAR2(4000)
AT                                    VARCHAR2(4000)
OPERATORID                            VARCHAR2(4000)
SUBSCRIBERID                          VARCHAR2(20)
TRANSACTIONID                         VARCHAR2(20)
```

One more thing. I have to deal with SQL*Plus only I can't use `DBI` with `DBD::Oracle` module because of Solaris issues. I want to solve this on my own but need your advice on these performance issues as I can't use hit and miss methods on them.

Comment: Your `cat` output looks like it is the contents of `VoucherQuery.sql` and not `QueryResult.$currentDate.log`? From your query it looks like `serialnumber` isn't unique, so unless Oracle allows non-unique primary keys I think it will break if you declare `serialnumber` to be a primary key

Comment: What are the *"Solaris issues"* that prevent you from using DBI?  With millions of records I think you are never going a reasonable reaction time using that SQL, because it starts by fetching up the entire database with the preceding value of the state column for each serial number. Once it has done that it filters the result by `at` and presumably throws away most of the work it has just done. I would start by doing `SELECT DISTINCT serialnumber FROM voucher WHERE at LIKE '&1'` and *then* correlate each record with its previous status. An *index* (not a PK) on `serialnumber` would be good.

Comment: @Borodin thanks for response.. You are right.. I have rectified my mistake.. But Primary cant be non-unique value... here combination of primary key & state could be the PK.. will it make any impact?
here is the explanation on DBI "http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Not+able+to+install+DBD%3A%3AOracle+on+sun+solaris." I won't mind if it takes too much time to get executed.. but problem is.. it just keeps waiting & not responding even in hour..I will try "DISTINCT" otption & will let u know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am far less experienced in Oracle than other databases, so this may well not be correct. But if it works it should certainly be faster than your existing SQL because it limits the data it is working on *first* before adding the `previous` column.

```
SELECT
  serialnumber,
  state,
  at,
  operatorid,
  LAG(state) OVER (PARTITION BY serialnumber ORDER BY at) AS previous
FROM
  voucher
WHERE
  serialnumber in (SELECT DISTINCT serialnumber FROM voucher WHERE at LIKE '&1')
```

Note that it won't produce exactly the same result as your own query because it will include all records relating to a given `serialnumber` as long as *at least one* of those records has an `at` column that matches `&1`.